# Double slit - higher dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, double-slit-experiment, spacetime-dimensions, huygens-principle

The double slit experiment is a real-life manifestation of the [Huygens principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle). As is well-known, this principle depends on whether the number of dimensions is ever or odd; as [Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821849743)<sup>1</sup> puts it,

> Observe, in contrast to formula $(31)$, that to compute $u(x,t)$ for even $n$ we need information on $u=g$, $u_t=h$ on all of $B(x,t)$, and not just on $\partial B(x,t)$.
>
> Comparing $(31)$ and $(38)$ we observe that if $n$ is odd and $n\ge3$, the data $g$ and $h$ at a given point $x\in\mathbb R^n$ affect the solution $u$ only on the *boundary* $\{(y,t)|t>0,|x-y|=t\}$ of the cone $C=\{(y,t)|t>0,|x-y|<t\}$. On the other hand, if $n$ is even the data $g$ and $h$ affect $u$ within all of $C$. In other words, *a "disturbance" originating at $x$ propagates along a sharp wavefront in odd dimensions, but in even dimensions continues to have effects even after the leading edge of the wavefront passes*. This is *Huygens' principle*.

Thus, **my question**: qualitatively speaking, how does the double slit experiment look in, say, $4+1$ dimensions? Is there any major difference as compared to the same experiment in our $3+1$ world?

---

1. See page 80. Here, we are solving the wave equation $u_{tt}-\Delta u=0$ in $\mathbb R^n\times(0,\infty)$, with $u(x,0)=g(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=h(x)$. Moreover, $B(x,r)$ is the closed ball with centre $x$ and radius $r$.

Comment: An equivalent (and appropriate in your case!) question would be how the Fourier transforms differ between odd and even dimensions.

Comment: The slits are usually assumed to be very long so you effectively work with 2d problem. Why should there be any difference in the higher dimensions?

Comment: You may first have to tell us what you want to call a "slit" in a world with 4 spatial dimensions. A 1-dimensional "hole" in a 3-dimensional "wall"? a codimension-2 (hence 2-dimensional) "hole"?

Comment: I agree with Luazanne and OON. In 4+1 dimensions, the same thing would happen, provided you used a 1-dimensional slit in a 2-dimensional wall projecting onto another 2-dimensional wall. If there is some 4+1 dimensional aspect to this question, you haven't explained it properly.