# Huygens principle

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, huygens-principle

Is there any law that says that the envelope coincides with the wavefront for any spatial dimension $n$?

If I am not wrong, Huygens principle is valid just for even spatial dimensions.

Is there some part of [Huygens principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) which is valid for all dimensions?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Huygen's principle states that every point on a wavefront can be treated as a source of secondary wavelets.  Are you asking for a justification of this idea?

Comment: @J.Murray The Huygens principle, at least from a naïve point of view, depends on the number of space-time dimensions because the solutions of the wave equation depend on the number of space-time dimensions. More precisely, on whether the number is even or odd. For some more details see [Double slit - higher dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346073)

Comment: @J.Murray I mean can I say that for example any wave front at time $t+\delta$ is the envelope of the wave front at time $t$? I am in $R^2$.
This is something that I read somewhere.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes it is what I have read. 
 I am wondering if I can say that in $R^2$ for example any wave front at time $t+\delta$ is the envelope of the wave front at time $t$. It is something that I read in a paper. It should not be true with respect to the fact that Huygen's principle is not valid for even dimensions!

Comment: The principle is valid in any number of dimensions. However the resulting wave front is different. For example, in 2 or 4 dimensions your flashlight would blind you, because the beam would partially reflect back from space. You can observe this by throwing a rock in a lake.

Comment: @safesphere you mean the envelope coincides with the wave front for any  n?

Comment: Not sure what you call envelope, but the wavefront at the next moment is a sum of wavelets from the current moment. This is what the principle says and it is correct for any number of dimensions. The difference is that in an odd number of dimensions this sum cancels in the reverse direction, so the wave only moves forward, but in an even number of dimensions this is not true. Shake a whip or a long rope and the wave runs away (1D). Turn off the lamp and it becomes dark (3D). Throw a rock in a lake and see that the wave expands, but also stays inside the circle and in the middle (2D).

Comment: PS. Also no sound echo in an empty space in 3D. You would always hear the echo of your voice in 2D or 4D.

Comment: @safesphere Thanks so much for the explanation. So helpful Indeed. Envelope is a surface which is tangent (at only one point) to each wavelet at an instant t. So with this explanation the envelope is the wavefront what actually I wanted.

Comment: @safesphere The principle is valid for every kind of wave or just in optic?
For example waves of sound, water, fire,....

Comment: My understanding is that the principle is valid for any wave anywhere, as long as the medium is linear (or, if in vacuum, the equations are linear) and therefore the waves obey the superposition principle of not interacting with each other. These include electromagnetic waves, sound, water, etc. The waves that do not obey the superposition principle include gravitational waves, turbulence on water, exceeding the speed of sound in air, saturation in transformers and tape, non linear springs or elastic materials. I am not sure if the Huygens principle fully applies to such interacting waves.

Comment: see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209_Making_waves_the_geometric_derivation_of_Huygens'_Principle_for_wave_propagation_and_the_problem_of_the_wake