# Higher dimension observer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, double-slit-experiment, spacetime-dimensions

In Quantum Mechanics (double slit electron experiment) a third dimension observer could only see two kinds of patterns in a screen:
-Two lines behind each slit if one chooses know the electron position;
-Wave interference if one chooses not knowing the electron position;

This is the duality particle-wave well knowing.

The question is: What should a possible higher dimension observer see if it decides with any higher dimension apparatus observe this experiment, should see the two lines, interference pattern, mix of two patterns or anything completely new and third dimensional incomparable?

Comment: Higher-dimensional observers would see the same thing.

Comment: related/possible dup: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346073/84967

Comment: Almost the same, but in that question suggested the double slit is in a higher dimension. The question is how a higher dimension oberserver should see a lower dimension experiment, a higher dimension apparatus interacts with a lower dimension experiment?